# Object template - Html.Display using ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got following display template for object ([source](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html)):

```
@model object

@if (Model == null) {
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText
} else if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) {
    @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText
} else {
    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => pm.ShowForDisplay && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(pm))) {
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) {
            @Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)
        } else {   
            <div>
                <strong>@prop.GetDisplayName():</strong> @Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

Which works great, until there is same key in `ViewBag`. For example following class

```
public class Article {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

should display (and will display with empty ViewBag)

```
Title: Awesome title
Text: Awesome text
```

however it displays following when `ViewBag.Title` is set to `"Detail"`

```
Title: Detail
Text: Awesome text
```

It is caused by `@Html.Display(prop.PropertyName)` that seem to prefer `ViewBag` value against model value. Any suggestions? I can't use `Html.DisplayFor` because I have only property name stored in string variable, not as expression for given model.

I guess I could clear viewbag and restore it later, but that doesn't look like good solution to me.

Edit: View looks like this:

```
@model Article

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detail";
}

@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-tabular-display-template.aspx - `@Html.DisplayFor(m => prop.Model)` works as expected. Who knew there was `Model` property in metadata..

Answer (score 1):

As for *ViewBag.Title* itself you could move assignment to it at the end of a page:

```
@model Article

@Html.DisplayForModel()

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Detail";
}
```

As for other *ViewBag* items you could use item names which are uncommon (with several leading underscores etc.)