# MVC3: set default DisplayFor template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

The default `DisplayFor` helper just throws some escaped text on the page.  Is there a way to wrap the default in a `<span>` or `<div>` without writing custom `DisplayFor` templates for each property you want to display?  Instead of it spewing out

```
Foo
```

I want it to spit out

```
<span>Foo</span>
```

I've seen a lot of articles for making the custom stuff; I use those quite often.  But most of my display stuff I just want to handle with simple CSS where the content is wrapped in a tag, and I can't find a reference on how to do this, or even if it's possible.

Comment: Sure use the 'object' template and override as follows
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019566/object-template-html-display-using-viewbag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure use the 'object' template and override as follows from ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties
[Object template - Html.Display using ViewBag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019566/object-template-html-display-using-viewbag)

By having your display template named object.cshtml you will apply to all types with numerable properties

There's a link to brad wilsons entry that contains the primary details
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own `HtmlHelper` extension

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString EnhancedDisplayFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("<span>");
        stringBuilder.Append(html.DisplayFor(expression));
        stringBuilder.Append("</span>");
        return new MvcHtmlString(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
}
```

and then use it like this

```
@Html.EnhancedDisplayFor(model => model.MyProperty);
```